# sqlcipher Xcode 4

Tags: sqlite, ios4, xcode4, sqlcipher

Hi~ I'm trying to use SQLCipher with Xcode 4.

But I can't build SQLCipher success.

And no error messeage.... just spend 30 up min to build....nothing happen...

like this(Capture image)... http://ppt.cc/sz!A (sorry I am not allowed to post image...)

(The strange thing is openssl.xcodeproj can build...)

Have some one build sqlcipher success with Xcode 4?

Please help me.....very appriciate.......thanks.......

------Edit 2011.5.18-------

Hi Stephen Lombardo

This is my Buid Phase(Image) → http://ppt.cc/c3_~

Am I miss something?

libsqlcipher.a still can't build.

Thanks~

Comment: Any errors? Post them. Something else happened that you didn't want? Describe it.

Comment: And `ld: library not found for -lsqlcipher`     
  
`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`   
   

`Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1`

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a link error the most likely cause is that you don't have your project setup to link the SQLCipher library. Go into your Project Build settings -> Build Phases -> Link With Binary Libraries and make sure that libsqlcipher.a and libcrypto.a are both listed there. If not, add them. Then clean the project and the rebuild.

Note: There is a new step-by-step tutorial on how to use SQLCipher with XCode 4 up on the site. If you step through the instructions it may help narrow down the problem: http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/